# element.length not working when using generics

Tags: function, dart, generics, parameters, element

My problem is this. I am passing arguments to a function that uses generics. For example I am passing element. I need to use `element.length` in the function but it gives me this error:

> The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!'). dartunchecked_use_of_nullable_value

```
    void main(List<String> args) {
        const List keyList = ['asd', 3, 'tyu', 67];
        const List valueList = ['dfg', 'ert', 4, 'lkj'];
        print(myMap(keyList, valueList));
    }

    Map myMap<K, V>(K key, V val) {
        final Map<K, V> myMap = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        myMap[key[i]] = val[i];
        }
        return myMap;
    }
```

I don't know if null aware operators can be used here, or if they solve the problem and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You defined your generic types, but your parameters are *lists* of that type. You did not make this clear to your compiler. For your compiler, `K` is now of type `List<dynamic>` while what you wanted it to be is just `dynamic`.

Changing it to make it fit (my guess of) your requirements:

```
Map<K, V> myMap<K, V>(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    final result = <K, V>{};
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      result[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please note that you are reinventing the wheel here. There already is a [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterables.html) that does this:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
    const List keyList = ['asd', 3, 'tyu', 67];
    const List valueList = ['dfg', 'ert', 4, 'lkj'];
    print(Map.fromIterables(keyList, valueList));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution solved my problem. Yes, this is reinventing the wheel as seen by your shorter solution. But I am new to programming and Dart and still don't know the existence of many useful methods. This one was just an exercise to grasp generics concept.